# Is the sum of two Brownian motions always a martingale, even if the two are possibly correlated?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Is the sum of two Brownian motions always a martingale, even if the two are possibly correlated?

I'm not sure, because on the internet I couldn't find the specific answer. I get correlation plays a role, but not sure how.

EDIT: Thanks to anyone who will answer. However, I sometimes find the lack of sympathy on this platform a bit unsettling. I thought this was a place where any student could ask a question, as simple as it might be, but I often get arrogant answers and of no help whatsoever.

Also, I'd rather not share the whole questions, for reasons you may infer by yourselves. I just know I have two brownian motions which might or might not be correlated, and I'm asked to state if their sum is always martingale or if they necessarily have to be independent/uncorrelated. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: @amWhy I think the meaning is: If $\{B(t)\}$ and $\{W(t)\}$ are  two Brownian motions defined on the same probability space, is $\{B(t)+W(t)\}$ necessarily a Martingale even if $B$ and $W$ are dependent?

Comment: The meaning of the question is quite clear to anyone who has any familiarity with the topic.  You should not mistake your own ignorance for lack of clarity in the question.

Comment: It's a problem statement question, @Eric.  No excuses.  You should be encouraging the user to improve their question, as you think you know it all.  This is no better than any other asker's "I have no clue!" questions.  But if you think snobbery exempts such askers when supported by you, then this site has a problem

Comment: @EricWofsey  While I agree with you the question is quite clear, it could still be improved (the question should not be mentioned only in the title; the OP should mention what he tried.) Let's try to stay civil on this wonderful site, despite differences of opinion.

Comment: I'm sorry @amWhy: if you think the question is clear enough, and I don't think it is hard for anyone beyond stochastic calculus 101 (see: not me), could you not just give me an answer? If I could add more information, I clearly would. I cannot.

Comment: @amWhy I tried to improve the question as I could! I hope it's enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I interpret the question to mean: If $\{B(t)\}$ and $\{W(t)\}$ are  two Brownian motions defined on the same probability space, is $\{B(t)+W(t)\}$ necessarily a Martingale even if $B$ and $W$ are dependent?

If you assume that $B$ and $W$ are both adapted and satisfy the Martingale property with respect to the   same filtration $({\mathcal F}_t)$   i.e.,
$$\forall s>t, \quad E[B(s)| {\mathcal F}_t]=B(t) \,,$$
$$\forall s>t, \quad E[W(s)| {\mathcal F}_t]=W(t) \,,$$
then the answer is positive from the definitions.

Without some assumption on the dependence of $B$ and $W$, the answer is negative. Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion, and recall that $E[B(1) | B(2)]= B(2)/2.$

Define a second Brownian motion by $W(t)=B(t+1)-B(1)$ and let $Z(t)=B(t)+W(t)$, so $Z(1)=B(2)$. Then
$$E[Z(2)-Z(1)|Z(1)]=E[B(3)-B(1) | B(2)]= B(2)-B(2)/2=B(2)/2 \,,$$
so $Z$ is not a Martingale.